# DSLR bright shots

Tags: dslr, white-balance

My DSLR Nikon d3200 shots were brighter than usual camera shots. the white balancing is on auto and the shots are taken not merely from direct sunlight. Is this because of lens?

Comment: What metering mode are you using? Can you post some examples, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of lens?

**No.** If the camera and lens are working correctly, it's not because of the lens. There are a number of possible explanations, but they mostly all relate to camera settings. Some possibilities:

- You set the exposure compensation such that the camera overexposed the shots.
- You metered the shot and locked the exposure, and then the lighting changed before you actually took the shot.
- You were shooting in manual mode and set the camera to overexpose the shot.
- You were using a metering mode that reads only part of the frame, and the rest of the frame was much brighter than the area that the meter read.